# Clojure function to get docstrings from functions in a namespace

Tags: clojure

I want to write a function that returns the names and docstrings of the public functions in my namespace, like so:

```
(ns familiar.core
  (:require [clojure.repl :refer [doc]]
            ...))

;; various functions with docstrings here

(defn help 
  "Halp!"
  []
  (let [fns (keys (ns-publics 'familiar.core))]
    (for [f fns]
      [f (with-out-str (doc f))])))
```

When I call `(help)` in the REPL, the docstrings don't come with the functions:

```
familiar.core=> (help)
([save-experiment ""] [load-experiment ""] [add-data ""] [help ""] ... )
```

But calling `(with-out-str (doc add-data))` in the REPL works as I'd expect:

```
familiar.core=> (with-out-str (doc add-data))
"-------------------------\nfamiliar.core/add-data\n([& coll])\n
Adds instances of variables with values at active date.\n  Examp
le:\n (add-data \"mice\" 6 \"cats\" 2 \"dogs\" 0)\n"
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`doc` is a macro, so it cannot evaluate the local `f` in the calling context. Instead, you are simply calling `(doc f)` ovr and over.

The easiest approach to solve this is to go around the `doc` macro, and look directly at the data that it uses to produce documentation: metadata on vars.

```
(defn help 
  "Halp!"
  [x]
  (for [[name var] (ns-publics 'familiar.core)]
    [name (:doc (meta var))]))
```

Comment: A worse alternative (just to illustrate the point) would be to replace `(doc f)` with `(eval \`(doc ~f))` in the original code.

Comment: Thank you! I've run into the same problem before and solved it the way A. Webb mentioned but your way is more sane.